# Effect of xslant and yslant as a transformation matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was looking for the effect of `xslant` and `yslant` in terms of a transformation matrix. E.g., why does the transformation of the point `(1,1)` by `xslant=yslant=1` not lead to a symmetric treatment of the coordinate. That is, the code:

```
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \draw (1,1) circle (1pt);
    \draw[red,xslant=1,yslant=0] (1,1) circle (1pt);
    \draw[blue,xslant=0,yslant=1] (1,1) circle (1pt);
    \draw[green,xslant=1,yslant=1] (1,1) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image: effect of xslant and yslant]

The position of the blue and red coordinates makes sense, but the position of the green coordinate doesn't, as it's not the linear combination of the blue or red re-positioning. So, what is the transformation matrix for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some trial and error eventually showed that the transform matrix is described by

[image: transform matrix]

So, for our case that gives the transform matrix

```
[ 1+(1*1) 1]
[   1     1]
```

which multiplied with the vector `[1,1`] gives `[3,2]`

Comment: No trial and error necessary: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/b79c4c5c632110079c3827ce4963a27e6d5d1742/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex#L390-L400

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. It's the linear combination of the two operations that is the not-so-obvious part; one could define it as (slant_x + slant_y)(coord), or slant_y(slant_x(coord)), but it is actually defined as slant_x(slant_y(coord)), that is, the coordinate is transformed in the y direction first, and that intermediate result is transformed in the x direction.